# emacs on Windows: .emacs is no valid file name

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I've found out where to put my .emacs file, but it seems it can't begin with a ".".

I tried naming it "emacs" or "_emacs", but how can I find out if it is used?

Comment: Put something in it and see if it works? [Installation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/Installing-Emacs.html)

Comment: E.g., add this at the end, then after startup take a look in buffer *Messages* to see if you find the message: (message "*************** MY DOT EMACS WAS LOADED!!!! ***************"

Answer (score 4):

You can always create the file using Emacs itself: <kbd>C-x C-f ~/.emacs</kbd>. The `~` represents your home directory, which you can set as environment variable `HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MsWindowsDotEmacs) page and [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/windows/faq3.html#startup) one for start up instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a file in Explorer, it won't allow you to use a .name (gives this error).

A simple work-around, if you have bash (cygwin, git-bash, or any other variant) installed is to use that to rename the file. It may also work in powershell or command prompt, I've not tested those.

Files can start with '.', this doesn't cause any trouble alone, but explorer won't let you name them with it.

Answer (score 1):

Recent versions of windows (e.g. Windows 7) seem to allow creation of a `.emacs` file using windows explorer. When creating/renaming the file simply enter `.emacs.` instead of `.emacs`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows Explorer disallows the creation of filenames starting with a dot. A simple workaround with builtin Windows tools is to create the file with a dummy name (eg. `_emacs`), then use cmd.exe to rename it:

```
cd path/to/file
ren _emacs .emacs
```

Answer (score 0):

To test if the `.emacs` that you are editing is the `.emacs` that is being loaded, you could put the following elisp command in it:

```
(minibuffer-message "it worked")
```

Now exit and restart emacs, while watching the minibuffer at the bottom of the screen to see if it appears (it will only appear for 2 seconds).

Answer (score 0):

Windows allows the creation and use of that type of file, but Windows Explorer does not allow a file to be named to that using Windows Explorer. Use another tool (like the command line, or emacs) to create the file with that name.